# Install TMS Edit Controls fails in Delphi 10

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, tms

I'm trying to install TMSEditControls in Delphi 10, but get the message "Required package 'DbxCommonDriver' not found".

I can't seem to find that package anywhere, so any hints to where I can get it or solve the install problem would be appreciated.

Comment: What Delphi SKU (Starter, Professional, Architect, etc.) are you using? And are you using 2010 (from the tags) or 10 (from the text)? They're not the same thing.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the Starter edition. I'm not sure what the difference between text and tags are? The edition says "Berlin 10.1".

Comment: Berlin 10.1 is not 2010. It's Berlin 10.1. The Starter Edition SKU does not include database support, so you will not find anything starting with `Dbx`, which is database related. Contact TMS to see if they have a version of their controls that do not require DB Express support.